# Can't connect PHP with Mysql using PDO

Tags: arch-linux

After compiling php typing

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-pdo-mysql
```

I could succesfully connect to the database, but then I enabled the openssl and mbstring extensions

I typed

```
./configure --with-openssl --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs
```

and

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --enable--mbstring --with-libmbfl
```

Now I'm unabled to connect php with mysql.

This is the code I'm using:

```
?php
$username = "phptest";
$servername = "localhost";
$password = "cucaramacara";
$dbname = "phpsampledb";


try{
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password$
  //set the PDO
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  echo "Connected succesfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Connection failed:".$e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

When I type `php` on the terminal it displays:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20131226/pdo_mysql.so' -
>   /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20131226/pdo_mysql.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown
>   on line 0

Comment: You're doing it wrong.  `./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-pdo-mysql --with-openssl --enable--mbstring --with-libmbfl`  It should be one command, not 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As yoonix noted, you are *Doing It Wrong*: the `configure` script should be run ***ONCE*** with ***ALL*** of the options you want to specify:

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-pdo-mysql \
             --with-openssl --enable--mbstring --with-libmbfl
```

---

*Calls to `configure` are not cumulative - they **overwrite** each other. The last one wins.*

Each option to configure specifies a change from whatever the vendor's defaults are, so what you are doing in your description is telling `configure` the following:

`./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-pdo-mysql`

> Please prepare to build PHP. Use all of the default settings, *except* I want to use the PDO MySQL driver.

so `configure` prepares a build with the PDO MySQL driver. Then you tell it
`./configure --with-openssl --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs`

> Please prepare to build PHP. Use all of the default settings, *except* I want OpenSSL enabled.

so configure prepares a build with OpenSSL enabled, and all the other defaults (goodbye PDO MySQL driver, since that's not *default* behavior).

Then you tell it
`./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --enable--mbstring --with-libmbfl`

> Please prepare to build PHP. Use all of the default settings *except* enable multibyte strings and `libmfl`.

so configure prepares a build with those options - No PDO (since that's not a default), and I think no OpenSSL (because I don't think that's a default either).

When you run `make` each time you're building with only the options specified *the last time you ran `configure`*.